# Plupload : error "code": 100, "message": "Failed to open temp directory

Tags: php, plupload

I am using plupload :Any ideas as to why I am getting this error? Here is my code snippet below. If the directory does not exist, it should create it and upload the file to that newly created folder.

```
$tempFolder = "uploadFolder";
$targetDir =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $tempFolder;
$cleanupTargetDir = true; // Remove old files
$maxFileAge = 5 * 3600; // Temp file age in seconds

// 5 minutes execution time
@set_time_limit(5 * 60);

// Uncomment this one to fake upload time
// usleep(5000);

// Get parameters
$chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunk"]) : 0;
$chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunks"]) : 0;
$fileName = isset($_REQUEST["name"]) ? $_REQUEST["name"] : '';

// Clean the fileName for security reasons
$fileName = preg_replace('/[^\w\._]+/', '_', $fileName);

// Make sure the fileName is unique but only if chunking is disabled
if ($chunks < 2 && file_exists($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName)) {
    $ext = strrpos($fileName, '.');
    $fileName_a = substr($fileName, 0, $ext);
    $fileName_b = substr($fileName, $ext);

    $count = 1;
    while (file_exists($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName_a . '_' . $count . $fileName_b))
        $count++;

    $fileName = $fileName_a . '_' . $count . $fileName_b;
}

$filePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;

// Create target dir
if (!file_exists($targetDir)){
    echo $targetDir;
    @mkdir($targetDir);
    }   
else{
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 99, "message": "Exist"}, "id" : "id"}');
}

// Remove old temp files    
if ($cleanupTargetDir && is_dir($targetDir) && ($dir = opendir($targetDir))) {
    while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
        $tmpfilePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;

        // Remove temp file if it is older than the max age and is not the current file
        if (preg_match('/\.part$/', $file) && (filemtime($tmpfilePath) < time() - $maxFileAge) && ($tmpfilePath != "{$filePath}.part")) {
            @unlink($tmpfilePath);
        }
    }

    closedir($dir);
} else
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 100, "message": "Failed to open temp directory."}, "id" : "id"}');


// Look for the content type header
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"]))
    $contentType = $_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"];

if (isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]))
    $contentType = $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"];

// Handle non multipart uploads older WebKit versions didn't support multipart in HTML5
if (strpos($contentType, "multipart") !== false) {
    if (isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
        // Open temp file
        $out = fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
        if ($out) {
            // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
            $in = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "rb");

            if ($in) {
                while ($buff = fread($in, 4096))
                    fwrite($out, $buff);
            } else
                die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
            fclose($in);
            fclose($out);
            @unlink($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
        } else
            die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    } else
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 103, "message": "Failed to move uploaded file."}, "id" : "id"}');
} else {
    // Open temp file
    $out = fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
    if ($out) {
        // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
        $in = fopen("php://input", "rb");

        if ($in) {
            while ($buff = fread($in, 4096))
                fwrite($out, $buff);
        } else
            die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');

        fclose($in);
        fclose($out);
    } else
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream "}, "id" : "id"}');
}

// Check if file has been uploaded
if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {
    // Strip the temp .part suffix off 
    rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);
}


// Return JSON-RPC response
die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : null, "id" : "id"}');
```

Comment: It's a permission issue.  Make sure that the web server has permission to read from and write to files in the temp directory.

Comment: Thanks @JackManey.  It seems this line :$cleanupTargetDir && is_dir($targetDir) && ($dir = opendir($targetDir)) . It might just be a permisison issue.